# Hide Drawer Item from the Drawer when opened

Tags: react-native

I would like to have a screen which to be part of the Drawer route but not to be visible (the Drawer Item) when the Drawer is opened. Here is my configuration:

```
const DrawerRoutes = {
    Home: {
        name: 'Home',
        screen: StackNavigator(HomeStack, { initialRouteName: 'HomeTab', ...navOptions })
    },
    Notifications: {
        name: 'Notifications',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'NotificationsTab', ...navOptions })
    },
    LastAdded: {
        name: 'LastAdded',
        screen: StackNavigator(VideosStack, { initialRouteName: 'LastAddedTab', ...navOptions })
    },
    ChangeLog: {
        name: 'ChangeLog',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'ChangelogTab', ...navOptions })
    },
    AboutUs: {
        name: 'AboutUs',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'AboutUsTab', ...navOptions })
    },
    Test: {
        name: 'Test',
        screen: StackNavigator(ProfileStack, { initialRouteName: 'ProfileScreen', ...navOptions })
    }
};

export const DrawerNav =
    DrawerNavigator(
        DrawerRoutes, {
            drawerWidth: windowWidth - Normalize(48),
            contentOptions: {
                activeBackgroundColor: Colors.selectedRowHeader,
                activeTintColor: Colors.navigationBar,
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: Fonts.light,
                    color: Colors.navigationBar,
                }
            },
            contentComponent: props => {
                return (<View style={styles.container}>
                    <StatusBar />
                    <Header />
                    <DrawerItems {...props} />
                    <LogOut {...props} />
                </View>);
            }
        },
        { headerMode: 'none' }
    );
```

In the code above the item 'Test' shouldn't be visible but I would like to be able to navigate to 'Test' with navigation.navigate('Test'). Navigation is working even when I make it from another screen (exactly as I want it) but the Drawer is showing it. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

From https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2021
If you want to hide test from the drawer.

```
class Hidden extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const Main = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Test: {
    screen: TestScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: <Hidden />
    }
  }
}, {});
```

Answer (score 11):

I have two ideas on this.
You can set `drawerLabel:()=>null` in `navigationOptions` in DrawerRoutes:

```
Test: {
screen: MyTestScreen,
navigationOptions: {
  drawerLabel: ()=>null,
}}
```

or in the MyTestScreen class :

```
static navigationOptions={
drawerLabel:()=> null,};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<DrawerStack.Screenname="ScreenName"component={ScreenComponent}options={{drawerItemStyle: {display: "none",},}}/>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly! I had a custom drawer with an image background where user has their profile photo. I wanted the screen to be a part of the drawer navigator but also didnt want to display the label, rather have an onPress on the picture with a navigation.navigate on the ImageBackground in the DrawerContentScrollView. Solved my issue!

Answer (score -1):

If you use react-navigation >= v.3, and you need to close the drawer from inside an component, you can do it easily with:

`navigation.closeDrawer();`

You only need access to the navigation property.
Here a small example:

```
const ChatRoomList = ({
  navigation, navigation: { navigate }, chatRooms, user,
}) => (sideBar ? (
  <TouchableList
    items={chatRooms}
    onPressItem={(item) => {
      navigate('ChatRoom', { chatRoomId: item._id, user });
      navigation.closeDrawer();
    }}
  />
)
```

Give it a try, for me it works like expected.